# Choose recursive/non-recursive directory iterator based on a run-time condition

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17, std-filesystem

I want to use methods `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` or `std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator` depending on a boolean. The code would be something like:

```
some_type dirIterator = isRecursive ? std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator : std::filesystem::directory_iterator;

for (const std::filesystem::directory_entry& entry : dirIterator(path))
{
    // common code for the two iterators
}
```

How can I accomplish this? If there are different approaches I would like to know all to choose the one I like more, but I think I prefer the simpler one :-)

I tried to use a function pointer but I do not know the "common" return type of the two iterators:

```
??? (*dirIterator) (const std::filesystem::path & dirPath);
```

Comment: There is no common return type, so this isn't expressible in C++ as-is. One option is to create your own "common_directory_iterator" which abstracts the iterator. Another is to templatize the code so it operates on both iterator types.

Comment: Is `isRecursive` a constant, or can it change at runtime?

Comment: `isRecursive` can change at runtime

Comment: @RaymondChen can you give full working code examples of both approaches?

Comment: One option would be to use [`std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator) for both cases (recursive and non-recursive iteration) - you just need to call [`disable_recursion_pending()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator/disable_recursion_pending) on it after every iterator increment to effectively get non-recursive iteration. see [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/fqqGqb1aa)

Comment: @Turtlefight that's really clever. I've included it in my answer, but feel free to submit your own answer and remove it from mine if you feel like this is plagiarism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`recursive_directory_iterator` and `directory_iterator` are distinct types, and they are not covariant. If you try to select one of two with the conditional `? A : B` operator, there is a problem, since `A` and `B` are unrelated types.

#### Template-based solution

However, both types of iterators share a common interface. Most importantly, they are iterable. This suggests that you could use templates to solve the problem.

```cpp
namespace fs = std::filesystem; // applies to all code in this answer

template <typename DirectoryIterator>
void doStuff(DirectoryIterator iterator) {
    // TODO: consider constraining this function with std::enable_if
    for (const fs::directory_entry& entry : iterator) {
        // ...
    }
}

// alternatively, make doStuff a generic lambda:
auto doStuff = [](auto iterator) {
    for (const fs::directory_entry& entry : iterator) {
        // ...
    }
}

// ...
if (isRecursive) doStuff(fs::recursive_directory_iterator(path));
else             doStuff(fs::directory_iterator(path));
```

#### Non-template solutions

Another solution is to put whatever you were going to do in the loop into a lambda:

```cpp
auto visitEntry = [](const fs::directory_entry& entry) {
    // ...
};

if (isRecursive) {
    for (const fs::directory_entry& entry : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(path)) {
        visitEntry(entry);
    }
}
else {
    for (const fs::directory_entry& entry : fs::directory_iterator(path)) {
        visitEntry(entry);
    }
}
```

This produces mild code duplication, but it's conceptually simpler than the template.

A clever solution by commenter @Turtlefight is to use `recursive_diretory_iterator` in both cases, and disable recursion after each iteration with [`disable_recursion_pending`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator/disable_recursion_pending):

```cpp
auto iterator = fs::recursive_directory_iterator(path);
for (const fs::directory_entry& entry : iterator) {
    // ...
    if (!isRecursive) iterator.disable_recursion_pending();
}
```

Comment: thanks Jan, I liked the generic lambda the most, I ended up making a function like `void IterateDir(auto iterator) { ... }`, the "auto" keyword was really the trick here, the "Non-template solution" is the one I was trying to avoid but thanks anyway for the detailed answer :-)

Comment: @andrepacheco ah right, I've removed it by accident during one of my edits. Now it's back in.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to implement this:

```
auto do_on_dir(const std::filesystem::directory_entry& entry) {}

auto do_on_all_folders(const std::string& path, bool isRecursive) {
    if (isRecursive) {
        for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(path)) {
            do_on_dir(entry);
        }
    }
    else {
        for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(path)) {
            do_on_dir(entry);
        }
    }
}

auto do_on_all_folders_recursive(const std::string& path) {}

auto test() {
    do_on_all_folders("path", false);
    do_on_all_folders("path", true);
}
```

```
auto do_on_dir(const std::filesystem::directory_entry& entry) {}

auto do_on_all_folders(const std::string& path) {
    for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(path)) {
        do_on_dir(entry);
    }
}

auto do_on_all_folders_recursive(const std::string& path) {
    for (const auto& entry :
             std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(path)) {
        do_on_dir(entry);
    }
}

auto test() {
    do_on_all_folders("path");
    do_on_all_folders_recursive("path");
}
```

```
auto do_on_dir(const std::filesystem::directory_entry& entry) {}

template <bool Recursive>
auto do_on_all_folders(const std::string& path) {
    if constexpr (Recursive) {
        for (const auto& entry :
             std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(path)) {
            do_on_dir(entry);
        }
    } else {
        for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(path)) {
            do_on_dir(entry);
        }
    }
}

auto test() {
    do_on_all_folders<true>("path");
    do_on_all_folders<false>("path");
}
```